# How to get line number from text file after an if statement

Tags: java

i was wondering how i can get a line number from a text file that meets certain conditions from an if statement. For example

```
if(textline == null){
     throw new Exception("There is no data in Line " + bufferedreader.getLineNumber() +1);
}
```

I want to get the line number when there is an empty row to throw an exception. 
I tried the above method but clearly that won't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: read lines and check equality to ""? (trim whitespaces as needed)

Answer (score 0):

Like I stated in the comments, you can read the line & then check:

```
if("".equals(line)) // use String.isEmpty after 1.6
```

Or if you don't want to count whitespaces you may:

```
if("".equals(line.trim()))
```

And throw your exception there. Obviously keeping track of line count is super easy with a counter that increases as you read each line.

Answer (score 0):

Use the subclass of [`BufferedReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) called [`LineNumberReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/LineNumberReader.html) in order to get the [`getLineNumber()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/LineNumberReader.html#getLineNumber%28%29) method.

Neither of these return `null` for empty lines, so you probably need to write this instead:

```
if (textline.isEmpty()) {
```

You may want to do it on lines with nothing but whitespace.

```
if (textline.trim().isEmpty()) {
```